# Using Checkbox and Shared Prefferences for settings Android

Tags: android, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activities. MainActivity and Settings. In settings activity I have few Check Boxes. I want to have boolean, if CheckBox is checked, boolean would be true and if not checked false.
And then I would use that value for settings in MainActivity. I tried with so many ways but I can't make it to work. 
How can I save boolean value using shared preferences, and save button state?
Edit: I tried with this code, but it doesn't work.

```
final SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences("myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);


        option1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                    boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked == true) {
                     option1.setChecked(customSharedPreference.getBoolean("myCheckBoxPref", true));         
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
                      editor.putBoolean("checked",true);
                      editor.commit();


                } else {
                     option1.setChecked(customSharedPreference.getBoolean("myCheckBoxPref", true));             
                      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
                      editor.putBoolean("checked",false);
                      editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
   public void putBooleanInPreferences(boolean isChecked,String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.commit();        
    }
    public boolean getBooleanFromPreferences(String key){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
        return isChecked;       
    }
```

**and in onCreate()**

```
 CheckBox checkBox = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_check_box);
        boolean isChecked = getBooleanFromPreferences("isChecked");
        Log.i("start",""+isChecked);
        checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("boolean",""+isChecked);
                TestActivity.this.putBooleanInPreferences(isChecked,"isChecked");
            }
        });
    }
```

Hope this may help you!

Comment: This worked! Thanks. I will accept your answer as soon as it's possible, the timer won't let me now.

Answer (score 1):

Use integer for storing boolean flags, where each bits in integer will represent one flag

So you will have flags at each bit representing soemthing you want:

FLAG at bit 1 for property 1 : 0x01
FLAG at bit 2 for property 2 : 0x02

And you build like that,

Now if somebody has checked checkbox 1, you should update the shared preference integer flag like

```
 MySharedPref.setCheckBoxFlags( MySharedPref.getCheckBoxFlags() |  0x01 )
```

This will set your first bit of your integer, telling that first checkbox is checked
Similarly you can store other checkbox preferences

In MainActivity if you want to know if checkBox 1 was checked you can do this

```
 if ( (MySharedPref.getCheckBoxFlags() &  0x01) > 0) // 1st is set, that means checkbox was checked
```

Now if checkbox was unchecked, say checkbox 1, you should clear the first bit, which you can do like this ....
    // This will unset the first bit
    MySharedPref.setCheckBoxFlags( MySharedPref.getCheckBoxFlags() & ~0x01 )

Based on integer from shared pref, you can show your checkbox, ticked or unticked in settings page